# How to calculate the derivative of a pythagorean distance function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Hello I'm a student learning calculus. Recently I stumbled upon a question that's been bugging me.

$$f(x) = ( (a-bx)^2 + (m-nx)^2 )^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

$f'(x)= ?$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: Hint: if you know the chain rule...

Comment: Take a look here, this may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2p_svlzBB8

Comment: Let $g(x)=(a-bx)^2 + (m-nx)^2$, and use chain rules...

Answer (score 1):

Let $h(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $g(x)=\left(a-b\cdot x\right)^{2}+\left(m-n\cdot x\right)^{2}$.

Then $f(x)=h(g(x))$.

The first derivative with $h'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ is
$$f'(x)=\frac{\frac{d}{d x}g(x)}{2 \sqrt{g(x)}}=\frac{(b^{2} +n^{2}) x-(a b+m n)}{\sqrt{\left(b^{2}+n^{2}\right) x^{2}-2\left(a b+ m n\right) x+a^{2}+m^{2}}}$$